# Вывод текста из класса в форму. Java Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Доброго времени суто !

Есть форма `jFrame`, которую написал вручную. Так же есть `класс`, который производит некие вычисления (реализовано на нитях), и после каждого вычисления я хочу выводить на форму текст (успешно выполнено на пример). Создавал экземпляр формы и обращался к компоненту, но все оказалось безуспешно. Как мне можно из этого класса выводить текст в компонент в форме ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Т.е, на сколько я понял, вы хотите обновлять данные на форме из другого потока? Обычно это делается так:

```
 SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //  Ваш код изменяющий данные на форме
    }
 });
```

**UPD:**

1. Первый способ - передавать при создании класса в него данные о форме:

   ```
   JFrame frame = new JFrame();
   ThreadClass cl = new ThreadClass(frame);
   ```
2. Второй способ, сделать отдельный standalone класс контекста который будет доступен со всего приложения:

   ```
   public  class Context{
         private Context instance = null;
         private JFrame frame;

         public Context getInstance(){
             if(instance==null){
                   instance = new Context();
             }
             return instance;
         }

         public JFrame getFrame() {
           return frame;
         }

         public void setFrame(JFrame frame) {
           this.frame = frame;
         }
   }

   /** код использования при создании формы **/

   private JFrame my_form;
   private Context ctx = Context.getInstance();

   my_form = new JFrame();
   ctx.setFrame(my_form);

   /** код использования из другого класса **/

   private Context ctx = Context.getInstance();
   SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
       public void run(){
           ctx.getFrame().form_element.setText("text");
       }
   });
   ```

Comment: `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
          Form x = new Form();
            x.filename.setText("Hello");
         }
      });`

почему то не работает =(

Comment: `JFrame` должна быть создана до этого. Из `invokeLater` вы можете обращаться к полям уже созданной формы.

Comment: Вот что я сделал: 1) В классе объявил экземпляр формы Form x = new From(); 2) Вставил код, который вы выслали 3) Обратился в том коде к компоненту. Но почему то не дает результатов.

Comment: А форма то где у вас выводиться? На момент `invokeLater` она уже должна быть отображена на экране

Comment: Дело в том, что форма выводиться в одном классе, а данные хочу кидать из другого класса

Comment: Есть два варианта: 1 - передавать вашему классу ссылку на форму при создании. 2 - использовать контекст - глобальный стандэлоне класс, который будет хранить информацию о вашей форме и использоваться во всем приложении

Comment: Если бы Вы добавили примеры в свой ответ, я был бы приемного благодарен !!! И можно было бы закрыть вопрос.

Comment: Сделал UPD в ответе

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас буду пробовать ! Как будет результат - дам знать и поставлю галочку ! Спасибо огромное !!!

Comment: Есть проблемка, ctx.getFrame().form_element.setText("text"); -< не видит моих компонентов (видит только методы стандартные для Frame). Что может быть не так ?

Comment: Определите в контексте свою форму не как JFrame а как она у вас в проекте определена.

Comment: Можете чат на пару минут ?

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28871/discussion-between-cobalt-and-kxxko).